# Should I tell the user how much time a process took?

Tags: user-centered-design, response-time

My project has some database queries and it may take a time.
Should I display the time taken of a query to the user after the query ends?

---

EDIT

This project is an industry software.
Users may or may not care about it.
We are concerned that showing the taken time may make user ask some unnecessary optimization needs.

Comment: K.I.S.S. Keep It Simple Stupid. If you aren't sure of the value and it isn't required, why do it? If the queries can be tailored by the user so as to take much longer than expected (or than the system can handle) then it makes sense to give some feedback so as to steer users towards more performant queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless they asked for it specifically, if it is not needed, and doesn´t help the user in any way, you should not put it. But keep in mind that if you expect the process to last longer than a few seconds, you should let the user know prior to the action being executed, just to avoid them closing the window/browser/tab or try to do it again.